# How to update RecyclerView on selected TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have an activity with tow tabs(with viewPager). inside viewPager is a fragment that have RecyclerView.

first tab is for (Monday-Friday) and second tab is for (Saturday-Sunday)

I want to retrieve data from database and show in recyclerview on each tab. but i cant update my recyclerView. Please help me to do that.
here is my code:

this is my Fragment code:

```
public class toDastgheybFragment extends BaseFragment {


    private List<DatabaseModel> Times = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private View mView;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_dastgheyb, container, 
false);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        Times = databaseHelper.getAllUsers();
        mRecyclerView = mView.findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);
        mAdapter = new DataAdapter(Times);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return mView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<DatabaseModel> LineList = new ArrayList<>();
        LineList.clear();
        mAdapter = new DataAdapter(LineList);
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        final List<DatabaseModel> m = db.getAllUsers();
        if (m.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
                LineList.add(m.get(i));
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        db.close();
    }
}
```

and this is my DataHelper code:

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MetroDB";//name of the 
database
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "stationtime";//name for the 
table
    static String db_path = "/data/data/ir.shirazmetro/databases/";
    private static final String Station = "station";
    private static final String Time = "time";
    private static final String Line = "line";
    private final Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + 
TABLE_NAME + "(" + Station + " TEXT," + Time + " TEXT," + Line + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    private boolean checkExist() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db_path + DATABASE_NAME, null, 
SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
        return db != null;
    }

    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(db_path + 
DATABASE_NAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME + 
".db");
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myInput.close();
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
    }

    public void importIfNotExist() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkExist();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void open() {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db_path + DATABASE_NAME, null, 
SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public List<DatabaseModel> getAllUsers() {
        List<DatabaseModel> contactList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
        String whatStation = C.whatStation;
        String whatLine = C.whatLine;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT " + Time + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " 
WHERE " + Station + " LIKE '%" + whatStation + "%' AND " + Line + " LIKE '%" 
+ whatLine + "%'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            do {
                DatabaseModel m = new DatabaseModel();
                m.setTime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Time)));
                contactList.add(m);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        return contactList;
    }

}
```

and finally this is my activity code:

```
public class station extends BaseActivity {
Toolbar mToolbar;
private TabLayout tbLayout;
private ViewPager vPager;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_station);

    final DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        helper.importIfNotExist();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.tlbr1);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        initView();
        setupWithViewPager();
        tbLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new 
TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }

}


public void line1(View view) {
    Intent line1 = new Intent(this, line1.class);
    startActivity(line1);
}

private void setupWithViewPager() {
    BasePagerAdapter basePagerAdapter = new BasePagerAdapter(this, 
getSupportFragmentManager());
    vPager.setAdapter(basePagerAdapter);
    tbLayout.setupWithViewPager(vPager);

}

private void initView() {
    vPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tbLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    backBtn = findViewById(R.id.backBtn);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.backBtn:
            line1(view);
            return;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use view pager addOnPageChangeListener to update the fragment data.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
               //   get your fragment instance first then call the method of 
               //   the fragment which updates the recycler view data.
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: I should write this code in my fragment or in my activity?

Comment: write it in your activity.